# Aggregating time stamped data into four minute intervals with exceptions

Tags: r, aggregate

I need to transform time-stamped data with 80-second intervals into 4-minute (240-second) intervals.

The two main challenges I have is the large number of columns, and the fact that a few of the intervals are not 80-second, that's why I need help. Below is a `head()` sample of my dataset:

```
> head(dataraw)
     GMT_DATE GMT_TIME ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z Vigilance Head-up Grazing Browsing Moving
1: 06/17/2018 09:36:00         78         38         87         0      35       0       35      1
2: 06/17/2018 09:37:20         18         17         25         0      46       0        0     26
3: 06/17/2018 09:38:40          7          4          8         0      69       0        0      0
4: 06/17/2018 09:40:00          4          0          4         0      70       0        0      0
5: 06/17/2018 09:41:20         11          8         14         0      29       0        0     11
6: 06/17/2018 09:42:40         27         20         34         0       0      58        0      0
   Grooming Resting Fleeing Unknown End Total
1:        4       0       0       5   0    80
2:        8       0       0       0   0    80
3:        5       0       0       6   0    80
4:       10       0       0       0   0    80
5:       15       0       0      25   0    80
6:       10       0       0      12   0    80
```

As you can see, time-stamps have been taken every 80-seconds, although some of the time-stamps are 160-seconds as seen below on rows `5` and `6`:

```
> head(dataraw[c(3626:3632),])
     GMT_DATE GMT_TIME ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z Vigilance Head-up Grazing Browsing Moving
1: 06/20/2018 18:09:20          0          0          0         0       0       0        0      0
2: 06/20/2018 18:10:40          0          0          0         0       0       0        0      0
3: 06/20/2018 18:12:00          1          0          1         0       0       0        0      0
4: 06/20/2018 18:13:20          0          0          0         0       0       0        0      0
5: 06/20/2018 18:14:40          0          0          0         0       0       0        0      0
6: 06/20/2018 18:17:20          4          0          4         0       0       0        0      0
   Grooming Resting Fleeing Unknown End Total
1:        0       0       0       0  80    80
2:        0       0       0       0  80    80
3:        0       0       0       0  80    80
4:        0       0       0       0  80    80
5:        0       0       0       0  80    80
6:        0       0       0       0  80    80
```

Hence, the best I can do is to aggregate by time-stamps having `00` in their `seconds` format. That is going from `09:36:00`, to `09:40:00`, to `09:44:00` etc.

How can I do this?

As for the values in columns `ACTIVITY_X`, `ACTIVITY_Y` and `ACTIVITY_Z`, they should be averaged when merged. For the rest of the columns, values can be summed when aggregated. Column `Total` will then have 240 for 4-minutes intervals (240 seconds).

I hope somebody can at least set me on the right track. Any input is truly appreciated!

```
> dput(dataraw[(1:280),])
structure(list(GMT_DATE = c("06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", "06/17/2018", 
"06/17/2018", "06/17/2018"), GMT_TIME = c("09:36:00", "09:37:20", 
"09:38:40", "09:40:00", "09:41:20", "09:42:40", "09:44:00", "09:45:20", 
"09:46:40", "09:48:00", "09:49:20", "09:50:40", "09:52:00", "09:53:20", 
"09:54:40", "09:56:00", "09:57:20", "09:58:40", "10:00:00", "10:01:20", 
"10:02:40", "10:04:00", "10:05:20", "10:06:40", "10:08:00", "10:09:20", 
"10:10:40", "10:12:00", "10:13:20", "10:14:40", "10:16:00", "10:17:20", 
"10:18:40", "10:20:00", "10:21:20", "10:22:40", "10:24:00", "10:25:20", 
"10:26:40", "10:28:00", "10:29:20", "10:30:40", "10:32:00", "10:33:20", 
"10:34:40", "10:36:00", "10:37:20", "10:38:40", "10:40:00", "10:41:20", 
"10:42:40", "10:44:00", "10:45:20", "10:46:40", "10:48:00", "10:49:20", 
"10:50:40", "10:52:00", "10:53:20", "10:54:40", "10:56:00", "10:57:20", 
"10:58:40", "11:00:00", "11:01:20", "11:02:40", "11:04:00", "11:05:20", 
"11:06:40", "11:08:00", "11:09:20", "11:10:40", "11:12:00", "11:13:20", 
"11:14:40", "11:16:00", "11:17:20", "11:18:40", "11:20:00", "11:21:20", 
"11:22:40", "11:24:00", "11:25:20", "11:26:40", "11:28:00", "11:29:20", 
"11:30:40", "11:32:00", "11:33:20", "11:34:40", "11:36:00", "11:37:20", 
"11:38:40", "11:40:00", "11:41:20", "11:42:40", "11:44:00", "11:45:20", 
"11:46:40", "11:48:00", "11:49:20", "11:50:40", "11:52:00", "11:53:20", 
"11:54:40", "11:56:00", "11:57:20", "11:58:40", "12:00:00", "12:01:20", 
"12:02:40", "12:04:00", "12:05:20", "12:06:40", "12:08:00", "12:09:20", 
"12:10:40", "12:12:00", "12:13:20", "12:14:40", "12:16:00", "12:17:20", 
"12:18:40", "12:20:00", "12:21:20", "12:22:40", "12:24:00", "12:25:20", 
"12:26:40", "12:28:00", "12:29:20", "12:30:40", "12:32:00", "12:33:20", 
"12:34:40", "12:36:00", "12:37:20", "12:38:40", "12:40:00", "12:41:20", 
"12:42:40", "12:44:00", "12:45:20", "12:46:40", "12:48:00", "12:49:20", 
"12:50:40", "12:52:00", "12:53:20", "12:54:40", "12:56:00", "12:57:20", 
"12:58:40", "13:00:00", "13:01:20", "13:02:40", "13:04:00", "13:05:20", 
"13:06:40", "13:08:00", "13:09:20", "13:10:40", "13:12:00", "13:13:20", 
"13:14:40", "13:16:00", "13:17:20", "13:18:40", "13:20:00", "13:21:20", 
"13:22:40", "13:24:00", "13:25:20", "13:26:40", "13:28:00", "13:29:20", 
"13:30:40", "13:32:00", "13:33:20", "13:34:40", "13:36:00", "13:37:20", 
"13:38:40", "13:40:00", "13:41:20", "13:42:40", "13:44:00", "13:45:20", 
"13:46:40", "13:48:00", "13:49:20", "13:50:40", "13:52:00", "13:53:20", 
"13:54:40", "13:56:00", "13:57:20", "13:58:40", "14:00:00", "14:01:20", 
"14:02:40", "14:04:00", "14:05:20", "14:06:40", "14:08:00", "14:09:20", 
"14:10:40", "14:12:00", "14:13:20", "14:14:40", "14:16:00", "14:17:20", 
"14:18:40", "14:20:00", "14:21:20", "14:22:40", "14:24:00", "14:25:20", 
"14:26:40", "14:28:00", "14:29:20", "14:30:40", "14:32:00", "14:33:20", 
"14:34:40", "14:36:00", "14:37:20", "14:38:40", "14:40:00", "14:41:20", 
"14:42:40", "14:44:00", "14:45:20", "14:46:40", "14:48:00", "14:49:20", 
"14:50:40", "14:52:00", "14:53:20", "14:54:40", "14:56:00", "14:57:20", 
"14:58:40", "15:00:00", "15:01:20", "15:02:40", "15:04:00", "15:05:20", 
"15:06:40", "15:08:00", "15:09:20", "15:10:40", "15:12:00", "15:13:20", 
"15:14:40", "15:16:00", "15:17:20", "15:18:40", "15:20:00", "15:21:20", 
"15:22:40", "15:24:00", "15:25:20", "15:26:40", "15:28:00", "15:29:20", 
"15:30:40", "15:32:00", "15:33:20", "15:34:40", "15:36:00", "15:37:20", 
"15:38:40", "15:40:00", "15:41:20", "15:42:40", "15:44:00", "15:45:20", 
"15:46:40", "15:48:00"), ACTIVITY_X = c(78L, 18L, 7L, 4L, 11L, 
27L, 19L, 23L, 21L, 19L, 24L, 25L, 13L, 15L, 31L, 52L, 71L, 141L, 
103L, 59L, 43L, 85L, 129L, 81L, 106L, 86L, 129L, 82L, 67L, 145L, 
120L, 95L, 97L, 139L, 160L, 147L, 83L, 102L, 84L, 90L, 92L, 84L, 
95L, 121L, 84L, 58L, 72L, 72L, 52L, 65L, 83L, 57L, 61L, 72L, 
82L, 88L, 116L, 125L, 126L, 79L, 49L, 51L, 77L, 84L, 99L, 96L, 
90L, 72L, 74L, 61L, 86L, 71L, 52L, 24L, 52L, 55L, 53L, 37L, 49L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 45L, 53L, 72L, 49L, 60L, 77L, 79L, 93L, 110L, 
76L, 108L, 63L, 78L, 78L, 83L, 66L, 40L, 30L, 75L, 29L, 30L, 
37L, 39L, 38L, 41L, 48L, 16L, 58L, 75L, 81L, 85L, 64L, 51L, 31L, 
33L, 76L, 65L, 76L, 63L, 75L, 59L, 60L, 44L, 54L, 51L, 68L, 75L, 
93L, 82L, 83L, 86L, 79L, 67L, 59L, 94L, 75L, 47L, 28L, 66L, 58L, 
53L, 34L, 31L, 40L, 35L, 45L, 33L, 47L, 42L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 21L, 
26L, 30L, 47L, 34L, 28L, 31L, 48L, 33L, 45L, 33L, 41L, 40L, 44L, 
53L, 25L, 38L, 27L, 44L, 96L, 42L, 55L, 49L, 44L, 46L, 45L, 51L, 
58L, 36L, 27L, 35L, 53L, 44L, 44L, 60L, 29L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 36L, 
37L, 32L, 23L, 35L, 46L, 58L, 63L, 67L, 166L, 123L, 44L, 53L, 
68L, 43L, 48L, 61L, 48L, 65L, 54L, 69L, 67L, 62L, 51L, 49L, 41L, 
42L, 39L, 58L, 40L, 52L, 46L, 38L, 48L, 28L, 32L, 48L, 42L, 39L, 
90L, 108L, 44L, 40L, 22L, 38L, 22L, 45L, 32L, 27L, 23L, 13L, 
53L, 32L, 45L, 62L, 55L, 48L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 29L, 52L, 18L, 17L, 
17L, 10L, 1L, 33L, 19L, 22L, 10L, 23L, 46L, 81L, 115L, 97L, 111L, 
75L, 44L, 75L, 86L, 35L, 32L, 24L, 18L, 20L, 29L), ACTIVITY_Y = c(38L, 
17L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 20L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 13L, 16L, 23L, 4L, 8L, 21L, 
46L, 105L, 133L, 131L, 64L, 34L, 76L, 94L, 51L, 80L, 58L, 69L, 
47L, 57L, 108L, 102L, 80L, 71L, 127L, 135L, 114L, 116L, 131L, 
100L, 77L, 131L, 127L, 72L, 114L, 87L, 54L, 97L, 88L, 43L, 45L, 
84L, 62L, 91L, 87L, 114L, 94L, 76L, 97L, 81L, 155L, 49L, 72L, 
89L, 125L, 113L, 63L, 66L, 78L, 82L, 44L, 96L, 53L, 47L, 20L, 
35L, 42L, 46L, 31L, 38L, 45L, 37L, 42L, 34L, 28L, 86L, 55L, 42L, 
62L, 63L, 113L, 95L, 131L, 215L, 79L, 90L, 43L, 42L, 54L, 47L, 
24L, 96L, 31L, 34L, 24L, 46L, 36L, 42L, 59L, 13L, 73L, 73L, 94L, 
109L, 89L, 28L, 26L, 38L, 105L, 60L, 129L, 48L, 59L, 81L, 67L, 
51L, 36L, 81L, 154L, 74L, 80L, 81L, 79L, 83L, 57L, 47L, 62L, 
75L, 57L, 43L, 33L, 66L, 58L, 81L, 20L, 16L, 27L, 25L, 34L, 15L, 
30L, 31L, 9L, 24L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 21L, 63L, 33L, 15L, 15L, 43L, 
25L, 28L, 23L, 30L, 21L, 24L, 40L, 18L, 35L, 16L, 37L, 120L, 
27L, 45L, 42L, 33L, 45L, 36L, 32L, 36L, 35L, 22L, 24L, 31L, 38L, 
32L, 46L, 21L, 22L, 20L, 22L, 21L, 25L, 22L, 18L, 22L, 26L, 43L, 
83L, 103L, 239L, 165L, 49L, 47L, 41L, 27L, 33L, 36L, 26L, 46L, 
25L, 36L, 55L, 42L, 41L, 39L, 16L, 25L, 22L, 43L, 28L, 36L, 30L, 
19L, 19L, 13L, 16L, 41L, 37L, 117L, 132L, 45L, 45L, 23L, 19L, 
29L, 19L, 55L, 43L, 38L, 15L, 11L, 52L, 28L, 32L, 45L, 71L, 53L, 
4L, 1L, 8L, 17L, 42L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 30L, 16L, 16L, 19L, 
51L, 68L, 111L, 108L, 105L, 97L, 69L, 22L, 54L, 80L, 22L, 19L, 
20L, 29L, 15L, 22L), ACTIVITY_Z = c(87L, 25L, 8L, 4L, 14L, 34L, 
22L, 25L, 22L, 23L, 29L, 34L, 14L, 17L, 37L, 69L, 127L, 194L, 
167L, 87L, 55L, 114L, 160L, 96L, 133L, 104L, 146L, 95L, 88L, 
181L, 157L, 124L, 120L, 188L, 209L, 186L, 143L, 166L, 131L, 118L, 
160L, 152L, 119L, 166L, 121L, 79L, 121L, 114L, 67L, 79L, 118L, 
84L, 110L, 113L, 140L, 129L, 139L, 158L, 150L, 174L, 69L, 88L, 
118L, 151L, 150L, 115L, 112L, 106L, 110L, 75L, 129L, 89L, 70L, 
31L, 63L, 69L, 70L, 48L, 62L, 73L, 69L, 72L, 56L, 60L, 112L, 
74L, 73L, 99L, 101L, 146L, 145L, 151L, 241L, 101L, 119L, 89L, 
93L, 85L, 62L, 38L, 122L, 42L, 45L, 44L, 60L, 52L, 59L, 76L, 
21L, 93L, 105L, 124L, 138L, 110L, 58L, 40L, 50L, 130L, 88L, 150L, 
79L, 95L, 100L, 90L, 67L, 65L, 96L, 168L, 105L, 123L, 115L, 115L, 
120L, 97L, 82L, 86L, 120L, 94L, 64L, 43L, 93L, 82L, 97L, 39L, 
35L, 48L, 43L, 56L, 36L, 56L, 52L, 26L, 35L, 32L, 28L, 34L, 37L, 
79L, 47L, 32L, 34L, 64L, 41L, 53L, 40L, 51L, 45L, 50L, 66L, 31L, 
52L, 31L, 57L, 154L, 50L, 71L, 65L, 55L, 64L, 58L, 60L, 68L, 
50L, 35L, 42L, 61L, 58L, 54L, 76L, 36L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 42L, 45L, 
39L, 29L, 41L, 53L, 72L, 104L, 123L, 291L, 206L, 66L, 71L, 79L, 
51L, 58L, 71L, 55L, 80L, 60L, 78L, 87L, 75L, 65L, 63L, 44L, 49L, 
45L, 72L, 49L, 63L, 55L, 42L, 52L, 31L, 36L, 63L, 56L, 123L, 
160L, 117L, 63L, 46L, 29L, 48L, 29L, 71L, 54L, 47L, 27L, 17L, 
74L, 43L, 55L, 77L, 90L, 72L, 11L, 2L, 14L, 34L, 67L, 22L, 19L, 
18L, 11L, 1L, 45L, 25L, 27L, 21L, 56L, 82L, 137L, 158L, 143L, 
147L, 102L, 49L, 92L, 117L, 41L, 37L, 31L, 34L, 25L, 36L), Vigilance = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
7L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), `Head-up` = c(35L, 46L, 69L, 
70L, 29L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 80L, 72L, 
73L, 62L, 73L, 64L, 38L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 39L, 
22L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 58L, 80L, 53L, 
31L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 76L, 63L, 12L, 63L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 80L, 
80L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 41L, 80L), 
    Grazing = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 58L, 66L, 72L, 67L, 38L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 63L, 0L, 
    9L, 75L, 80L, 68L, 69L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Browsing = c(35L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 21L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Moving = c(1L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 4L, 7L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 17L, 7L, 
    5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 7L, 10L, 
    30L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Grooming = c(4L, 8L, 
    5L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 6L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    8L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 
    8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Resting = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Fleeing = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Unknown = c(5L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 
    25L, 12L, 0L, 7L, 13L, 28L, 49L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 38L, 13L, 36L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 52L, 
    23L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 42L, 
    11L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 61L, 12L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    8L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), End = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 37L, 19L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 58L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 69L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 41L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 39L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 79L, 80L, 39L, 14L, 
    59L, 34L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 39L, 0L
    ), Total = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
    80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L)), row.names = c(NA, -280L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000006b01ef0>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would generate table with all possible times (without seconds, for example), where second column is group index, then do left_join from dplyr to the original table, at the end aggregate by this artificial index. 
Btw, it's very convenient to do so, if you plan to make a plot in ggplot, you just write aes(x=.., y=.., col=index)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please forgive me if I don't understand exactly what you mean as I'm learning R. I think I might be able to do the `left_join()` part but I'm not sure about how I could generate the table you talk about? The data I have spands from `6/17/2017` at `9:36:00` until `6/24/2017` at `10:04:00`, if that helps. Also, how could I do the average and summing of the values?

Comment: I write in main branch

Answer (score 1):

First, make standard POSIXct format from your columns GMT_DATE, GMT_TIME
then

```
time_seq_by_seconds = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-06-17 09:36:00"), as.POSIXct("2017-06-24 10:04:00"), 1)
number_of_groups = round(length(time_seq_by_seconds) / 80) +1
groups = do.call(c, lapply(1:number_of_groups, function(x){ rep(x,80)} ))
groups = groups[1:length(time_seq_by_seconds)]

indexed = as.data.frame(cbind(as.character(time_seq_by_seconds), groups))
colnames(indexed) = c("datetime","group")
library(dplyr)
joined = left_join(dataraw, indexed, by = c("GMT_DATETIME" = "datetime"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your message. I used your code and got: ```Error: `by` can't contain join column `GMT_DATETIME` which is missing from LHS
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace```

Comment: change columns in your original dataset and concatenate them into new one GMT_DATETIME. library lubridate converts into different formats. Then dataraw = mutate(dataraw, GMT_DATETIME = paste(dataraw$GMT_DATE, dataraw$GMT_TIME ) )

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I added the line: ```dataraw$GMT_DATETIME<-as.POSIXct(paste0(dataraw$GMT_DATE, "-", dataraw$GMT_TIME), format = "%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S")``` before your code and then ran your script as is. I get the error: ```Error in left_join_impl(x, y, by_x, by_y, aux_x, aux_y, na_matches) : 
  cannot join a POSIXct object with an object that is not a POSIXct object``` Any ideas of what could go wrong?

Comment: apply as.character to both columns in both datasets, but i guess you should use space instead of dash between date and time

Comment: For some reason I get `NA`s for the full column when using pace instead of dash.

Comment: I used the scrit with this lines at the end:```indexed$datetime<-as.character(indexed$datetime)
dataraw$GMT_DATETIME<-as.character(dataraw$GMT_DATETIME)
joined = left_join(dataraw, indexed, by = c("GMT_DATETIME" = "datetime"))
head(joined)``` However, the output is a table with a column `group` with just `NA`s.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using any hacky way of dealing with date-time treat them as `POSIXct` objects. We can combine `GMT_DATE` and `GMT_TIME` into one `datetime` column and convert them to actual date time objects. We can now create groups of 4 minute interval each using `cut` and then `sum` them all together. I created an extra column `row` with value 1 which can be later used to calculate average of "ACTIVITY" columns.

```
library(dplyr)

dataraw %>%
  tidyr::unite(datetime, GMT_DATE, GMT_TIME, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), 
         row = 1) %>%
  group_by(group = cut(datetime, breaks = "4 mins")) %>%
  summarise_at(-1, sum) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("ACTIVITY")), ~. /row) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row) 

# A tibble: 94 x 15
#    group ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z Vigilance `Head-up` Grazing Browsing..
#  <fct>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <int>     <int>   <int>    <int>    
# 1 2018…       34.3      19.7        40           0       150       0       35...
# 2 2018…       14         9.33       17.3         0        99      58        0...
# 3 2018…       21        10          23           0         8     205        0...
# 4 2018…       22.7      17.3        28.7         0         0      38        0...
# 5 2018…       19.7      11          22.7         0        41       0        0... 
# 6 2018…       88        94.7       130           7       225       0        0... 
# 7 2018…       68.3      76.3       103          18       199       0        0...  
# 8 2018…       98.3      73.7       123.          0        38      63        0...
# 9 2018…      107        69         128.          0         3     164        0...  
#10 2018…       98        70.7       121.          0        12     144       21... 
# … with 84 more rows, and 3 more variables: Unknown <int>, End <int>, Total <int>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I'm experiencing the following error:``` > dataraw %>%
+   tidyr::unite(datetime, GMT_DATE, GMT_TIME, sep = " ") %>%
+   mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")) %>%
+   group_by(group = cut(datetime, breaks = "4 mins")) %>%
+   mutate(row = 1) %>%
+   summarise_at(-1, sum) %>%
+   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("ACTIVITY")), ~. /row) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   select(-row)
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `group` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable ```

Comment: @juancda4 not sure...we are not changing any grouping variable here and this seems to work on the sample data provided. I did a minor edit. Can you check on a fresh R session ?

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting: ```> library(dplyr)
> dataraw %>%
+   tidyr::unite(datetime, GMT_DATE, GMT_TIME, sep = " ") %>%
+   mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), 
+          row = 1) %>%
+   group_by(group = cut(datetime, breaks = "4 mins")) %>%
+   summarise_at(-1, sum) %>%
+   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("ACTIVITY")), ~. /row) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   select(-row) was
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row) was"```

Comment: @juancda4 Sorry, I had a typo there. I have corrected it. Can you check now?

Comment: I'm getting the same as before now: ```> library(dplyr)
> dataraw %>%
+   tidyr::unite(datetime, GMT_DATE, GMT_TIME, sep = " ") %>%
+   mutate(datetime = as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"), 
+          row = 1) %>%
+   group_by(group = cut(datetime, breaks = "4 mins")) %>%
+   summarise_at(-1, sum) %>%
+   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("ACTIVITY")), ~. /row) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   select(-row)
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `group` can't be modified because it's a grouping variable```

Comment: @juancda4 Do your columns have different structure then what you have shown? Do the order of columns differ? Can you run this on sample data which you have shared and see if you get any error? because I am not getting any error at my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191367/discussion-between-juancda4-and-ronak-shah).

Comment: @juancda4 were you able to figure this out?